# Cocos2D-X: image resizing then cutting parts to CCSprite

Tags: android, ios, xcode, image-resizing, cocos2d-x

I'm creating a Cocos2D-X project under XCode for iOS. Then I'm planning to transfer the final code to Android.

What I'd like to do is to make a function to load images and resize them arbitrarily in memory. Then, from the resized image I will cut parts out of it and will create CCSprite objects... The real problem I have is to get a resized image before cutting parts.

I know that Cocoa/UIImage can achieve that, but I don't won't to use Objective-c code so that the Android port will be easier. I want to do everything in C++/Cocos2D-X if possible.

I've tried to use ImageMagick Magick++ source code in my XCode project, but without luck because I can't compile it.
I've tried to use CCImage, but there no resizing function in it.

So my question is : Is there a way to do the resizing of image files in Cocos2DX? IS there an alternative way to reach my goal?

Thanks,Jean

Comment: You have already finish cutting, and making new Sprites for them, why don't you resize the cut sprites instead of the original image?

Comment: Yeah, that what I've planned to do, as I've stated in another comment below. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this rescale/cut process part of your app, or is this to attempt to fit the apps graphics to a number of Android screen resolutions? If the latter is the case, I wouldn't recommend it.

You have to understand that resizing and cutting can be done in any order. So you don't really need to resize your image first, you can also cut it first and resize it later. To resize just use the sprite's scale property to scale it up or down.

As for cutting the image it really depends on how you want to cut it. There are many ways how you could cut parts off an image (cut along borders, cut out arbitrary shape, cut out transparency, etc).

Comment: Cutting parts is for a puzzle game. It's not really about screen resolutions. What I think I'll do is to use all images in higher resoltuion, then cut and use ScaleX,ScaleY properties of a CCSprite to show those parts.

Answer (score 0):

To create a sprite that is an extract of a bitmap, you can do like this and avoid creating new bitmaps (not sure this is what you're looking for) :

CCSprite *cutSprite = CCSprite::spriteWithTexture(texture,CCRectMake(originX,originY,width,height));

Comment: I already had the cutting function working in my code. The only trouble is about resizing. I haven't found a real process to resize before cutting off. I'll dig into the CCTexture2D class to see if I can find something. thanks